# Generating variables with a loop in Python from Matlab

Tags: python, loops, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to convert a program from Matlab to Python.

In Python I wrote:

```
age=np.arange(start_age, start_age+D, deltat)
For num in age:        
if age[:]<(65):
    Y=1
    break
else
    Y=0
    break
    break
H = (1/r) * (1 - math.exp(-r * max(0, (65 - age[:])))
A = ((1 - theta) * r - rho) / theta + 0.5 * ((1 - theta) / theta ** 2) *(    _lambda **2)
g = (1/A) * (math.exp(A * (D - (age[:] - start_age))) - 1)
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

- for `age` I need a series of integers that goes from 20 to 79;
- for `Y` I need that for every value in age,

  - for number smaller that 65 I need a 1 and
  - for every number bigger than or equal to 65 I need a 0.
- `H`, `A` and `g` are simply functions.

I have two problems:

1. It doesn't allow me to work with values inside `age`.
2. The loop for `Y` doesn't work.

Comment: There are numerous problems with this code. It's not indented correctly. It uses several undefined variables. `for` should be lower case. `else:` is missing a colon. And why do you have 2 `break` statements in that `else` block? Also,  `H`, `A` and `g` are **not** functions, they are simple expression assignments using those undefined variables I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is what you want for `age` and `Y`:

```
In [314]: age = np.arange(20,80,5)
In [315]: Y = np.where(age<65, 1, 0)
In [316]: age
Out[316]: array([20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75])
In [317]: Y
Out[317]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

For the rest, I won't try to test the code (too many undefined variables), but I think this will work (for scalar parameters):

```
H = (1/r) * (1 - np.exp(-r * max(0, (65 - age)))
A = ((1 - theta) * r - rho) / theta + 0.5 * ((1 - theta) / theta ** 2) * (_lambda **2)
g = (1/A) * (np.exp(A * (D - (age - start_age))) - 1)
```

`math.exp` works on scalar values, `np.exp` on arrays.

---

with limited testing:

```
In [318]: H = (1-np.exp(max(0, 65-age)))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

oops, wrong `max`.  That's the Python scalar one:

```
In [319]: H = (1-np.exp(np.maximum(0, 65-age)))
In [320]: H
Out[320]: 
array([ -3.49342711e+19,  -2.35385267e+17,  -1.58601345e+15,
        -1.06864746e+13,  -7.20048993e+10,  -4.85165194e+08,
        -3.26901637e+06,  -2.20254658e+04,  -1.47413159e+02,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
In [321]: g = np.exp((1-(age-20)))
In [322]: g
Out[322]: 
array([  2.71828183e+00,   1.83156389e-02,   1.23409804e-04,
         8.31528719e-07,   5.60279644e-09,   3.77513454e-11,
         2.54366565e-13,   1.71390843e-15,   1.15482242e-17,
         7.78113224e-20,   5.24288566e-22,   3.53262857e-24])
```

Comment: Thank you! I am still learning all of this and I do get confused with the different functions of numpy and not numpy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for num in age:
   if num < 65:
     Y=1
     break
   else:
     Y=0
     break
H = (1/r) * (1 - math.exp(-r * max(0, (65 - age[:])))
A = ((1 - theta) * r - rho) / theta + 0.5 * ((1 - theta) / theta ** 2) *(    
_lambda **2)
g = (1/A) * (math.exp(A * (D - (age[:] - start_age))) - 1)# equation (A11)
```

if you use the for loop like this then you can use evry element of the list with num in stead of age!

***BUT:***

The way you are using the beaks, you will always stop at the first element of your array and correct me if i am mistaking but i don't think that is what you want... so or you lose the breaks or you can just check on the first element like this:

```
if age[0] < 65:
```